# If a website has a 5 second time delay before showing the login form, is that likely a security measure?

Tags: authentication, web-application, web-browser

The JP Morgan Chase homepage has a 5 second delay before login form appears. If you refresh the delay is always there. If you fail to input a proper password, the failed login page has no such delay when the page is loaded, regardless of how many refresh requests.

Is the homepage implementing some sort of security measure?

Comment: Could just be terrible coding practices.

Comment: It's just banking-grade UX. It's actually not that bad, at least you can use a password manager on their form, unlike others that have an on-screen keyboard or ask for only parts of the password.

Comment: @AndréBorie there are good reasons for both of those implementations, aren't there?

Comment: @Tim Maybe, maybe not. I've seen banks that use a JS timeout to present a fake and entirely unnecessary "processing" bar. Maybe it makes users think something important and difficult happening, but I wouldn't say that's really a *good* reason to do it.

Comment: @Tim No. If the machine is compromised to the point where the keyboard is not safe, an on-screen version won't be any safer. The best solution would be 2-FA which sadly I have yet to see on any bank I've been at.

Comment: @AndréBorie hence only entering 3 of the characters

Comment: @Tim what if the attacker changes the page to ask for all of them? Besides, with the characters randomly selected and the usual 6 or 8 numeric characters of the password, it will still take only a dozen of logins or so to get the entire password without even tampering with the page.

Comment: @AndréBorie There are some pretty smart reasons behind some banks disabling 2-FA. See the following http://thenextweb.com/worldofbanking/2016/09/21/how-to-think-like-a-hacker/#gref

Comment: @user1800340 I disagree. Disabling 2FA just because idiots don't know how to use it is a bad idea (and the solution is time-limited, as idiots will eventually learn how to use it as more services adopt it, like Google, Facebook, etc). Not to mention, 2FA using TOTP requires zero infrastructure (no SMS, etc) so there's really no good reason not to offer it.

Comment: @AndréBorie It doesn't pass the smell test when you say there's no good reason not to use 2FA, yet a multi billion dollar organization with heavy investments in cyber security R+D is currently running a successful pilot IA program based on deliberately decommissioning 2FA.

Comment: @user1800340 I still do not see any clear reason in the linked article why they *eliminated* 2FA. Not making it mandatory is indeed understandable, as some people may not know how to use it. However why not offer it as an option? Also, the article seems to imply that fraud detection algorithms and 2FA are mutually exclusive. Why not have both?

Comment: @AndréBorie from what I saw, they want to direct attackers to the path of least resistance in order to have greater predictability of attack patterns. Leave the front door open lets more get in, but you know where they're all going. It potentially discourages attackers from trying to find more advanced vulnerabilities as well that would end up being harder to detect. Obviously I'm not privy to their internal R+D, I can only try to put myself in their shoes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45879/discussion-between-andre-borie-and-user1800340).

Comment: @AndréBorie Chase actually does have 2FA, but a computer is deemed "safe" once a successful login happens (so a compromised computer would still be a risk, but not a compromised password)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Is the homepage implementing some sort of security measure?

If you are referring to https://www.chase.com, then nope, it's just slow to load and do the transition thing. Terrible UX maybe, but this is not a security feature. A login cracking bot would not typically use the user interface anyway.

Basically, it's a banking website, and terrible UX is sadly the norm.

---

While this particular case may not be security related, it's not uncommon to have rate-limiting between login requests. This would have to be implemented in the back-end code to effect all requests to be effective.

Comment: It should also be noted that this page appears to implement no delay *between* login attempts, only before the first attempt. This adds no security benefit. This is not a security feature.

Comment: My bank's UX is pretty good, at least as far as the design and load times go.

Comment: OT, but they have won multiple awards for their UX/UI so I'm skeptical when I hear it's terrible. But at least it's settled that this isn't a security featured.

Comment: @JanDvorak mind sharing which bank it is?

Comment: @user1800340 I doubt most awards focus specifically on authentication. It's possible to have a decent menu system and still have an enragingly stupid login process. In the case of Chase however, I suspect it's more about priorities. Gotta get that low introductory API offer on screen ASAP, login, shmogin.

Comment: @andre it's Airbank. They only operate in Czech republic, but they have some screenshots of the internet banking.

Answer (score 6):

One possible scenario where this delay could be because of a security measure is if the site is using something like a [Client Puzzle Protocol (CPP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_Puzzle_Protocol). This does not appear to the case with https://www.chase.com/, but **CPPs can be used prevent denial of service attacks against slow hashing functions**. It is basically an implementation of [Proof-of-Work system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system). More details [here](http://Prevent%20denial%20of%20service%20attacks%20against%20slow%20hashing%20functions?).

The basic idea is to force the client to do a significant amount of work, and prove it has done so, before you will accept a username/password pair and try to validate it. Basic overview of the approach from the linked post:

> The server generates a random puzzle, and sends the puzzle to the
>   client. The server generates the puzzle in a way that it can predict
>   reasonably well how much effort will be required to solve the puzzle
>   (e.g., 100ms of computation). The client solves the puzzle, and then
>   sends the solution along with the user's username and password.
>
> In a web setting, this would probably be implemented with Javascript:
>   the login page would contain the Javascript code to solve the puzzle
>   and the puzzle description. A legitimate user's web browser would run
>   the Javascript on the page, which would solve the puzzle and include
>   the solution in the form along with the username and password.

Based on how this is implemented, a site could delay loading of the login page until the client (your browser) solves the puzzle. Again a bad UI design -- I'd just disable the login button until the puzzle is solved and enable the button for login form submission once the client has a solution.

Comment: +1 to *"CPPs can be used prevent denial of service attacks against slow hashing functions"*

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code using Chrome:

`view-source:https://www.chase.com/`

the

`<form name="homeLogonForm" class="container-fluid chase-home-login" action="https://mfasa.chase.com/auth/alogin.jsp" method="post" autocomplete="off">`

element is present when the page loads so it's definitely not "hidden" from simple bots via JavaScript but rather appears to be a UX decision to delay it's presence.

Without asking Chase Bank I can only provide conjecture that this was done for usability reasons discovered during their testing phase.